# Script for deleting the oldest folder until a certain threshold

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to make a script in PowerShell that calculates the used space of a directory and if is it greater than a threshold I want to delete the oldest folder based on creation date until I go under the threshold.

I managed to do something like this, but I do not understand why my `while` condition is not acting how I want it.

```
$directory = "D:\TEST"   # root folder
$desiredGiB = 25    # Limit of the directory size in GB

#Calculate used space of the directory
$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $directory -recurse |
            Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1GB) + " GB"
# store the size of the folder in the variable $size
$size = "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum/1GB)
Write-Host "$size"
Write-Host "$desiredGiB"

#loop for deleting the oldest directory based on creation time
while ($size -gt $desiredGiB) {
    # get the list of directories present in $directory sorted by creation time
    $list = @(Get-ChildItem $directory |
            ? { $_.PSIsContainer } |
            Sort-Object -Property CreationTime)
    $first_el = $list[0]    # store the oldest directory
    Write-Host "$list"
    Write-Host "$first_el"
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $directory\$first_el

    #Calculate used space of the Drive\Directory
    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $directory -recurse |
                Measure-Object -property length -sum)
    # store the size of the folder in the variable $size
    $size = "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum/1GB)
    Write-Host "$size"
}
```

Comment: `$size = "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum/1GB)` really creates a string! You want to keep $size an int for comparing and just output that string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've made the modification and it seems that is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$desiredGiB = 25

while ($size -gt $desiredGiB) {
    # ...
    $size = "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum/1GB)
    # ...
}
```

You are comparing an integer with a string here.

You could do this instead, to keep an integer value in $size:

```
$desiredGiB = 25

while ($size -gt $desiredGiB) {
    # ...
    $size = $colItems.Sum / 1GB
    $displayedSize = "{0:N2}" -f $size
    # ...
}
```